# (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError) in heroku, however works in local host and Heroku local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am building a super basic fighting game dictionary. The app works on localhost, and on Heroku local no problems.

here is my model

```
class Vocabulary < ApplicationRecord
  validates :word, presence:true
  validates :definition, presence:true

  has_many :users, :through => :favorites
end
```

here is my schema

```
create_table "vocabularies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "word", null: false
    t.string "definition", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Here is the Error i receive when running heroku run rails console

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:53:in `_assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'Word' for Vocabulary. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)
```

I've tried:
Heroku rake db:migrate,
resetting my Database,
deleting app off heroku and rebuilding,
crying a lot

I'm completely out of ideas so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When does the error appear?  What's the stack trace?

Comment: Please edit question with stacktrace of the error

Comment: Where do you send from the 'Word' attribute? It seems like you are using it with capital 'W'

Answer (score 0):

So I had exact same problem with my app. I had added a new field in the model and for some reason, while pushing the changes, heroku was not picking up the field and was showing unknown attribute error. However when i check in the heroku console, i could see, it actually there.
Neverthless here is my steps to resolve it.

1. First reset the db in heroku with `heroku rake pg:reset` (assuming you are using pg)
2. Then, run the migration again... - `heroku rake db:migrate`  (while running this migration, it should log out that it is actually running that particular migration with the field you wanted to add).
3. if you have seed data then... - `heroku rake db:seed`

Comment: What if this is not working on a live app? How do you fix it when you can't reset the database?